# Is there a way to retrieve all printers and their printer trays in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, printing, printers

My goal is to to retrieve all printers and their printer trays so that a user can select a printer and a tray to print a pdf file silently on Desktop (Win/Mac). I am searching for an existing plugin with the mentioned functionality but I don't find any mentioning the functionality in the documentation.